# Error while calling stored procedure in Postgres using Spring boot JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure in Postgres

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE reset_disabled()  
    LANGUAGE plpgsql  
    AS $$
    DECLARE
    BEGIN  
    UPDATE regional_price_info
           SET disabled = NULL;
    END;  
    $$;
```

I tried to call procedure from the repository class in two ways however both not worked

1. Use @Query annotation

   ```
   @Query(value = "CALL reset_disabled();", nativeQuery = true)
   void priceActivator();
   ```

   I got error

   > org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
2. I tried with @Procedure annotation

   ```
   @Procedure(value = "reset_disabled")
   void priceActivator2();
   ```

   I got error

   > 2023-02-22T07:43:00,013 [scheduling-1] [INFO ] com.zageno.pricing.activator.PriceActivator priceActivatorByValidity [28] - Triggering price activator procedure
   > Hibernate: **{call reset_disabled()}**
   > 2023-02-22T07:43:00,016 [scheduling-1] [WARN ] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions [137] - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42809
   > 2023-02-22T07:43:00,017 [scheduling-1] [ERROR] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions [142] - ERROR: reset_disabled() is a procedure
   > **Hint: To call a procedure, use CALL.**
   > Position: 15

   In above error log  (highlighted in bold) , Hibernate query using "CALL" and error is suggesting use "CALL" this seems contradictory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured out solution

If SP performs a DML operation like (Insert,Update) add following annotations along with @Query;

```
@Transactional 
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Query(value = "CALL reset_disabled();", nativeQuery = true)
void priceActivator();
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add  `@Transactional`
`@Modifying` tags above of the `@Query` because without them spring thinks you return resultset within your query.

> ```
> @Transactional
> @Modifying
> @Query(value = "CALL reset_disabled();", nativeQuery = true)
> void priceActivator();
> ```